# How to redirect pages during the maintenance to home page on IIS 7?

Tags: seo, iis7

I have IIS 7 website.

I need to redirect users during maintenance time to home page from other sub pages within site.

for example

if user request `http://www.example.com/products/234`

I need system to show default message, site under maintenance not 404 error

How it can be done in IIS 7?

Comment: You just trailed off at the end there. Did you forget something?

Comment: I think that's it

Answer (score 2):

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Found">
         <add wildcard="*.php" destination="/default.htm" />
      </httpRedirect>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: my pages without extensions.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `app_offline.htm` feature. There is a great answer on StackOverflow about this:

[How to use app_offline.htm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153449/asp-net-2-0-how-to-use-app-offline-htm)

We use this for our .Net sites and it works well.